# Native Base, React Native.. Should I be setting the tab size somehow

Tags: react-native, native-base

Using the tab bar with Native Base, works fine.. except the page of each tab will leak into the other tab. Should I bet setting a width somewhere? How would I do that?

For example I could have Tab1 selected, and you would be seeing Tab2 slightly on the right.

Also is there anyway to put the tab bar in the header? so when I scroll on the page it will remain.

```
  <Content theme={maintheme}>
                        <Tabs>
                            <ChatList tabLabel='Chat' />
                            <Discover tabLabel='Discover' />
                            <Notifications tabLabel='Notifications' />
                            <Profile tabLabel='Profile' />

                        </Tabs>
                    </Content>
```

Is my issue because some of my pages are wrapped in `<View> </View>` and not     `<Container>
</Container>`?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue. You need to include a Container and Content for each of your tab files.

index.ios.js:

```
<Tabs>
    <TabOne tabLabel="Tab 1"  />
    <TabTwo tabLabel="Tab 2"  />
</Tabs>
```

tabOne.js:

```
export default class TabOne extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <Text>I am Tab 1</Text>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
};
```

tabTwo.js:

```
export default class TabTwo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <Text>I am Tab 2</Text>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
};
```